# Como adicionar novas chaves à um dicionário?

Tags: python-3.x, dicionário

Seguinte, eu estou fazendo um programa que é um sistema de controle acadêmico, acontece que na hora de adicionar os professores, por exemplo, ele não está criando novas chaves para os professores no dicionário. Ele está simplesmente substituindo-as 
Aqui as funções para adicionar e consultar:

```
def addProfessor(cpf, nome, departamento):
global dicProfessores
dicProfessores = {}
if cpf not in dicProfessores:
    dicProfessor = {"Nome":nome, "Cpf":cpf, "Departamento":departamento}
    dicProfessores[cpf] = dicProfessor
    print("Professor cadastrado com sucesso.")
else:
    print("Erro de cadastro.\nEste professor já está cadastrado no sistema.")


def consultarProfessor(cpf):
if cpf in dicProfessores:
        dicProfessor = dicProfessores[cpf]          #definindo uma variavel para a chave do dicionario de professores
        for chave,elem in dicProfessor.items():
            print(chave + ": " + str(elem))
else:
    print("Este professor não é funcionário desta faculdade.")
```

e aqui o código para testar(ainda está incompleto):

```
 print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>BEM VINDO AO SISTEMA DE CONTROLE ACADÊMICO<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<")
print("")
print("")
print("Selecione onde você deseja fazer modificações: \n ")
print("1 - Professores\n2 - Alunos\n3 - Disciplinas\n4 - Turmas\n5 - Sair")
escolha = input("Digite o número corresponda a uma das opções: ")
if escolha == "5":
    print("Fim do programa.")
    break
else:
    while True:
        if escolha == "1":
            print("O que você deseja fazer?\n ")
            print("1 - Adicionar professor\n2 - Consultar professor")
            print("3 - Atualizar professor\n4 - Deletar professor\n5 - Voltar\n")
            escolhaP = input("Digite o número corresponda a uma das opções: ")
            if escolhaP == "5":
                break
            else:
                while True:
                    if escolhaP == "1":
                        print("\nDigite 'cancelar' para voltar.")
                        cpfP = input("Digite o cpf do professor: ")
                        if cpfP == "cancelar": break
                        nomeP = input("Digite o nome do professor: ")
                        if nomeP == "cancelar": break
                        departamentoP = input("Digite o departamento do professor: ")
                        if departamentoP == "cancelar": break
                        else:
                            addProfessor(cpfP, nomeP, departamentoP)
                    elif escolhaP == "2":
                        print("\nDigite 'cancelar' para voltar.")
                        cpfP = input("Digite o cpf do professor: ")
                        if cpfP == "cancelar".lower(): break
                        else:
                            consultarProfessor(cpfP)
```

Comment: Você colocou o dicionário `dicProfessores` como uma variável global dentro da função `addProfessor`, acredito que o problema esteja aí. As variáveis globais devem ser criadas na camada mais externa do aplicativo (mas o melhor mesmo é evitá-las ao máximo).

Minha sugestão é criar uma classe-coleção de professores. Nela você colocaria as funções de pesquisar por professor e adicionar quando não existir.

Comment: Sim, eu bem que gostaria de usar classe, mas meu professor não quer que agente use classe nesse projeto, mas eu vou tentar colocar os dicionários dentro da interface e tirar do modulo de funções

Comment: Ae, agora foi, foi só tirar o dicionário como variável global e colocar ele for das funções